# how an autoencoder denoise an image

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, autoencoder

i am using denoising autoencoder to denoise the image in the unsupervised way.But still after implementation of the denoisng autoencoder i am unable to understand how an autoencoder network know which kind of noise present so that it minimize it.How it understand it is noise or signal.Are there any mathematics behind it? I hope experts may help me understing this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Roughly auto encoder tries to take advantage of stable patterns. Thus noise, as random unstable patterns, is ignored.

Comment: @NikosM. can you please provide some links related to this stable pattern

Comment: The auto encoder NN's structure derives the stable patterns present in most of the data. So given enough data and considering that noise patterns are random thus unstable, only the stable ones will be present in the majority of the data, thus those found. In essence it is a codification of the data. Any paper on how autoencoders work will make this clear.

Comment: @NikosM. none of the paper is writing how it works? how it distinguish signal and noise? from your comment can you please clarify what is stable pattern ? as i am new to this i am not getting what actually stable pattern mean

Comment: A stable pattern is present, more or less the same, in the vast majority of the data, unlike noise which is random and unstable, even if it has some pattern. Thus the ANN of the autoencoder, will codify these patterns as weights in its layers, this is how it works. It works as any ANN, only it produces the same output, thus the internal representation of the autoencoder NN, reflects the patterns that should be stable (given the architecture)

Comment: @NikosM. if signal and noise has same pattern how does it distinguish?Details explanation i am not getting sir.

Comment: Then it cannot distinguish, but this case is highly unlikely. So in the majority of cases it works.